# Webpack and angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I'm trying to run simple app with angularjs and webpack , here is my code :
**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">

Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

        <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function mainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.firstName="John",
    $scope.lastName="Doe"
}
```

**Webpackconfig.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: {
    filename: './bundle.js'       
  }
};
```

**main.js**

```
var jquery = require("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js");
var angular = require("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular.min.js");


var app = require("./app.js");
```

**bundle.js**

```
?? I don't know what i sholud write here !!
```

also i've seen this : https://github.com/jeffling/angular-webpack-example
the question is how can i run this correctly ?

Comment: If you need help just make an issue in the project and I'll do my best!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**bundle.js** is generated by webpack so I think that you don't need to write this file.

The correct name for Webpack config file is webpack.config.js. With this file in place you can launch compilation with `webpack` or `webpack --watch` to continuously compile you bundle file as you modify your code.

I've create a `angular-index.js` to wrap Angular as CommonJS module. Here is the source code :

```
require('./angular.min.js');
module.exports = angular;
```

And I've merged `main.js` and 'app.js' in one single file

```
var jquery = require('jquery');
var angular = require('./angular-index');

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', require('./mainCtrl'));
```

And finally, I've added `mainCtrl.js`. This one is just the function definition of the controller.

```
module.exports = function($scope) {
  $scope.firstName = 'John';
  $scope.lastName = 'Doe';
};
```

For better and detailed explication please read this blog post https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/08/angularjs-browserify/. My working code is here https://github.com/jean-rakotozafy/angular-webpack-template

Comment: You can type `npm start` to compile and watch and run `http-server` (`sudo npm install -g http-server` if not yet installed) in other console to run the app.

Comment: sry for this question : why should i use command line to run it ?

Comment: thx maaaan,i've run it, one more question if u don't mind : i'm working on .net and angular project , and now we want to add webpack .
how can i run your github project without npm ?

Comment: You can find in package.json, scripts/start section, the command executed by `npm start`. So you can just do `webpack --progress --colors --watch` instead of `npm start`.

Comment: Sorry :). The blog post that I mentioned in my response use gulp: https://github.com/basti1302/angular-browserify. Perhaps, their example is more suitable for your use case.

Comment: You're welcome ;). This link may help http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx. Good luck!