# Where is the scriptsIn function in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I use the `scriptsIn` function in `Laravel` 5.3 to combine all Javascript files in `assets/js` folder. I use the AngularJS 1.x framework to write js files with this structure:

```
--resources\
-----assets\
--------js\
-----------app.js
-----------controllers\
-----------------....js
-----------directives\...
```

I combine all js file with Elixir in Laravel 5.3:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
    mix.scriptsIn('resources/assets/js'); 
});
```

However, when I upgraded to Laravel 5.4, Elixir is not supported. Instead, Laravel Mix is used. So, `scriptsIn` is not available. Is there any function with the same purpose in Laravel 5.4? How to combine all js files?

Comment: Could you explain what `scriptsIn()` does?

Comment: may be it will help you https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers

Comment: @PaladiN: I want combine all js files in assets/js folder and subfolders to app.js and put it into public/js folder

Comment: @IndreshTayal: what function in helpers? In `Laravel` 5.3, `Elixir` compile my js files when run `gulp` command with `scriptsIn` function. However, I don't find this function in Laravel 5.4. Read more in https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand from your comment, you want to add all the JS files first to `app.js` and then copy it to `public/app.js`. To perform this there is [a basic example](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/basic-example.md).

I am plucking the piece of code from the example. It is as easy as it used to be:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.sass('src/app.sass', 'dist')
   .js('src/app.js', 'public');
```

1. Compile the Sass file, `./src/app.sass`, to `./public/app.sass`
2. Bundle all JavaScript (and any required modules) at `./src/app.js` to `./public/app.js`.

You could change the path as your directory structure. This should help you.

You need to use the code in [Webpack.mix.js](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/webpack.mix.js). You could have a look at the updated config file in Laravel 5.4.

**Edit:**

I am not much experienced with `Angularjs` but i have some experience with `Angular2` where we need to create the class and export it and Webpack automatically gets the chunk of the codes and bundles into it's bundle.js.

You could have a look at these solutions provided for angularjs and Webpack:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26497742/3887342

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27500432/3887342

Comment: I use Angularjs. I put `var mainApp= angular.module('mainApp',[...])` in app.js, and controllers (for example, `mainApp.controller('somethingCtrl',...)`) in separated files. I don't have any code to import this controllers into app.js. Do you know how to require them into app.js before bundle by `Laravel Mix`?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem when updating to `5.4`

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
    mix.scriptsIn('resources/assets/js'); 
});
```

now becomes:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.sass('app.scss')
   .combine('resources/assets/js');
```